# Centering a Muses radio player with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have generated a Muses radio player and got the following code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                MRP.insert({
                'url':'http://radio.visiondecristo.org:8000/radio',
                'codec':'mp3',
                'volume':100,
                'autoplay':false,
                'buffering':5,
                'title':'',
                'bgcolor':'#FCFFFD',
                'skin':'simple-green',
                'width':300,
                'height':122
                });
                </script>
```

This code displays the player which is hosted in the Muses server.  The issue I have is that, I'm unable to center this player using CSS.  Can someone shed some light on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried with the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with Materizecss valign-wrapper.

```
<div class="valign-wrapper">
  <p class="valign">...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the class "musesStyleReset" defined by the DIV that is generated by the script. You can then manipulate this in the CSS:

```
   .musesStyleReset {
        margin: 0px auto;
        display: block;
   }
```